# Archive formats capable of appending data to a file

Tags: database, storage, hdf5, archive

As in the title.

I'm looking for an (uncompressed) archive format, which would allow for appending data to a file in the existing archive without unpacking a whole archive (or loading a whole file to RAM) as well as fast data read and write. The file is meant for storage of float arrays in a hierarchical structure, along with their attributes if that changes anything.

Btw I do want to store data in a single archive to allow for rapid data compression. Taring the whole directory structure seems to be too expensive in terms of both time and computing power.

If it's possible I would like the archiver to have available libraries for C++, Julia and Python, however it's neccessary to be compatible only with one of them.

I've been looking for something like that and I've found some tools, but currently with no avail. Things I've currently found, but do not fully meet my expectations;

1. HDF5 - here the issue is caused by library's performance. For a rather big datasets a considerable bottleneck (the fastest time I've been able to pack ~ 26 GB of text in the archive was close to 25 minutes. Readout along with saving data back as text files took less, than 5 minutes.
   1.1.    JLD2 (Julia only) - the only alternative HDF5 implementation I'm aware of. Performance-wise it's signifficantly superior to the official implementation, but does not allow for appending data to an existing arrays.
2. Uncompressed .zip file along with wxFile C++ library - does seem to almost work (except for accidental data corruption, which happens sometimes). I'm not sure, if I would be able to make it work, but seems to be an interesting alternative.
3. SQLite - does seem like a viable option, however speed will still probably be signifficantly inferior to catalog-based structure.

Sadly anything out of theese doesn't doesn't fully meet my expectations, and I'm currently unable to find any other alternatives.

I've been looking for something like that and I've found some tools, but currently to no avail. Things I've currently found but do not fully meet my expectations;

1. HDF5 - here the issue is caused by the library's performance. For rather big datasets a considerable bottleneck (the fastest time I've been able to pack ~ 26 GB of text in the archive was close to 25 minutes. Readout along with saving data back as text files took less, than 5 minutes.
   1.1. JLD2 (Julia only) - the only alternative HDF5 implementation I'm aware of. Performance-wise it's significantly superior to the official implementation, but does not allow for appending data to existing arrays.
2. Uncompressed .zip file along with wxFile C++ library - does seem to almost work (except for accidental data corruption, which happens sometimes). I'm not sure, if I would be able to make it work, but seems to be an interesting alternative.
3. SQLite - does seem like a viable option, however, speed will still probably be significantly inferior to the catalog-based structure. Sadly anything out of these doesn't fully meet my expectations, and I'm currently unable to find any other alternatives.

Alternatively I could just keep using catalog-based structure, however it's still far from optimal (compression does take only ~ 50% more time, than creation of the archive, which is deleted just after anyway).

Comment: HDF5 is designed to be efficient with large data files. However, I/O performance  depends on your procedure, data schema, and file settings (chunking, compression, etc). It's hard to comment without seeing the code. (Also, I use Pythons h5py and pytables packages, not Julia.)  I/O performance depends on the number of writes/reads than the amount of data. In other words, it is much faster to write 100 250MB increments than to write 10,000 2.5 MB increments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked h5py, HighFive (C/C++) and Julia's implementation, however, Julia was still the fastest one. In my case, there were ~900 000 increments of a few kB each, HDF5 is designed to write significantly fewer much bigger databases, so it doesn't fit too well here. That's also why I'm asking for alternative libraries/archive formats, and not about code optimization (btw as I've checked the optimization almost didn't matter here. It did change CPU load, but the time remained almost constant. Both ExDir and Zarr performed much better here.)